# error when trying to use stellar-hd-wallet (Node.js)

Tags: javascript-sdk

Hi we are tying to use the node.js version of the stellar-hd-wallet in ionic-angular. However, calling the StellarHDWallet.generateMnemonic() gives the following error:

*ERROR in ./node_modules/stellar-base/lib/transaction.js*
*Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'*

Any ideas of how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

I made a Git repo to test out your issue, and I wasn't able to reproduce the error:

https://github.com/morleyzhi/stellar-hd-wallet-test

I don't know your specific setup, but can you check the following?

- Is your project importing a different version of `stellar-base`? If so, what happens when you remove your project's install of `stellar-base`?
- Have you tried deleting node_modules and re-installing?
- If none of those ideas work, could you point me to a Git repo that reproduces this bug?

Comment: Did some further research and found out that this issue might be related to the angular 6 breaking webpack compilation https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-base/issues/128. The guys from stellar took out the crypto library from stellar base in version 0.13 due to this problem. But the stellar-hd-wallet for Node.js is using version 0.11

Answer (score 1):

Update: Upon my request, the guys from stellar-hd-wallet published a new release (0.10.0) that includes the necessary updates.